# Rust Polars filter string input eagerly

Tags: string, rust, filter, rust-polars

I am trying to understand the 2 modes (lazy, eager) in Polars. I Found a way to do this lazily:

```
let out = df
        .lazy()
        .select([col("A"), col("B")
        .filter(col("B").str().contains(input))])
        .collect()
        .unwrap().head(Some(10));
```

But how to do this eagerly? There is an example:

https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/docs/eager/index.html#filter
which I couldn't make work with str().contains(). And Do I understand correctly that col("") is specific for lazy and column("") for eager?

```
// create a mask to filter out null values
let mask = df.column("sepal.width")?.is_not_null();

// apply the filter on a DataFrame
let filtered_df = df.filter(&mask)?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a `Series`, the method is not called `str` like on `Expr`s, but `utf8` (see https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/series/struct.Series.html#method.utf8). In your case, you would use it like this:

```rust
let filtered_df = df.filter(&df.column("B")?.utf8()?.contains(input)?)?;
```

Note that there are multiple uses of the `?` operator which require that your function returns a compatible `Result` (such as a `PolarsResult`).